# How can prevent OS admin to see oracle procedure?

Tags: oracle

I developed a program that golden code is on oracle DB.
How can I sell my product and don't worry about reading my procedure on oracle.
I have to install product on customer computer. He could use orapwd.exe and online unwrap to see my procedure. Is there any way to prevent him?

Comment: you may want to check this: http://www.pfclobfuscate.com/2012/04/welcome-to-pfclobfuscate/

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle's built-in `WRAP`utility to obfuscate the code.

Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/wrap.htm).

Comment: If you are that worried about the source you could [code it entirely in C](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370) and then embed the generated library into the application using `CREATE FUNCTION function_name AS LANGUAGE C LIBRARY lib_name NAME name` but then, if you want to be paranoid and get your tin-foil hat out, they still might examine the assembly code that gets generated.